# What is the purpose of adding 子 in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

娘がなかなか起きない。よく寝る子だ。
It means my daughter has a hard time waking up. She sleeps a lot.
but I can't figure out the purpose of adding 子.

Comment: "but I can't figure out the purpose of adding 子." - Do you understand what the 子 means in itself? What do you think the sentence would mean without it? Does it seem grammatical without it? How would you analyze it? Basically - what is your thought process here? In order to properly explain why something is done, we must first understand why you expect it not to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

よく寝る is a relative clause, which modifies noun 子.

So whole "よく寝る子だ。" means "(She) is a child, who sleeps well/often."